# Ruby project with testlink jenkins and testLink plug-in

Tags: ruby, maven, plugins, jenkins, testlink

i am new in jenkins IC and maven.
I am using testLink plug-in for jenkins to do automation test, so i start with the "Jenkins TestLink Plug-in Tutorial".

And today i would like to know if it is possible to make the same thing but with a ruby file instead of a java file (and after that if all is working fine, with PL-SQL).

I googled a lot but there is not concrete way to make it.
(I think there is something to do with a maven goal, or something to config in jenkins but i don't know what).

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but thought it would be good to leave an answer here anyway.

The short answer is yes. The plug-in is language agnostic, but test format oriented. It currently supports TestNG, JUnit and TAP.

If your use case produces any of these formats (or if you can use adapters to convert your test report) then you can probably use one of the existing result seeking strategy to automate your test suite.

All the best,
Bruno